# npm err missing script webpack-dev-server

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm making a Reactjs app with wepback and i can't figure out why npm run webpack-dev-server is not working.

I installed the package and even installed it globally. every time i'm getting the same error as mentioned.

my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var dev = require('webpack-dev-server');


var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
    devServer: {
    inline:true,
    port: 8008
  },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/,
                include : APP_DIR,
                loader : 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "redditgallery",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Wix project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "ser": "wepback-dev-server -d"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/tamirhuber/RedditGallery.git"
  },
  "author": "Tamir Huber",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/tamirhuber/RedditGallery/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/tamirhuber/RedditGallery#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1"
  }
}
```

this is the error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "webpack-dev-server"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: webpack-dev-server
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\redditGallery\npm-debug.log
```

any thoughts?

Comment: you have `"ser": "wepback-dev-server -d"` and no `webpack-dev-server` in devdependencies...

Comment: I was having the same issue, and I used this:   devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  compress: true,
  port: 9000
} in my webpack.config file and it work.

Answer (score 4):

replace your script tag with this in package.json and run it with npm start

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
```

install the dependency using npm install webpack-dev-server --save

Answer (score 2):

You might need so install webpack and webpack-dev-server for your script to work. So:

`npm install webpack webpack-dev-server --save-dev`

Then everything you have installed locally and globally you can use it when you run any of the npm scripts, as the `.bin/` folder gets mounted in the process.

Another thing you have to have in mind is, if the webpack config is into another folder, you need to pass the `--config path/to/config` parameter.

`npm run ser`

Run the command above and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The webpack-dev-server is run through webpack when you start webpack. You don't need to start the dev server specifically.

When you type `npm run whatever` npm goes into your `package.json` file and looks for the `scripts` part. There it will look for `whatever` and run that command. You don't have any `webpack-dev-server` in your `scripts`, that's why it's saying it can't find it.

If you want to be able to type `npm run webpack-dev-server` you have to put `webpack-dev-server` inside your `scripts` in `package.json`. I think you can also simply run `webpack-dev-server` if you install it globally like this `npm install webpack-dev-server -g`